# SQL data export

Tags: excel, ant

I have the below script to execute SQL file.

```
 <target name="dataExcel" >
            <sql classpath="/ojdbc14.jar"      driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"     
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"      
            userid="scott"password="tiger"    
            src="/generateData.sql"  /> 
            </target>
```

Is it possible to spool data to Excel file? I need to automate SQL data export to Excel using script.

Edit 1

```
<project name="xlsx task"> 

  <taskdef name="xlsx" 
     classname="net.sourceforge.ant4x.biz.ms.XlsxTask" 
     classpath="PATH/TO/ant4x.jar"/> 

  <target name="xlsx"> 
    <xlsx file="/path/to/file.xlsx">
        <clone sheet="The_Sheet_To_Clone" rows="1-10">
            <column name="C" mergewithnext="true">
                <prefix value="[COLUMN C]EOL"/>
            </column>
            <column name="D">
                <prefix value="EOL[COLUMN D]EOL"/>
            </column>
            <column name="E"/>
        </clone>
    </xlsx>
  </target> 

                    </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sql task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html) has `output` property where you can specify `csv` file which will contain SQL results.

If you want to generate xlxs file you can use [Txt2XlsxTask](http://ant4x.sourceforge.net/ant-text-to-xlsx.html) where you specify the input file obtained from sql task and xlsx output file.

Comment: Does it have an option to specify xlsx instead of csv?

Comment: @user75ponic you may use http://ant4x.sourceforge.net/ which should be able to convert csv to xlsx

Comment: I have edited my question, how to integrate SQL script to execute with ant-xlsx?

Comment: Thanks Oleg, appreciated.